# How to force keyboard not overlap the stack panel

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am new to WP development and trying to get hands-on.

If you look at wallet pin screen, focus is automatically set to textbox so that user can start typing and also the keyboard does not hides/overlaps *done* & *cancel* button.

[image]

Also, If you hit back key, those buttons remain at bottom as shown below.
[image]

I am also trying to have same kind of UI. However, In my case

1. I am not able to set focus to textbox as soon as page is loaded. I
   can't get .Focus() method of textbox in OnNavigatedTo event. Where
   should i do this ?
2. When i manually tap textbox to enter a value, the keyboard overlaps
   my stackpanel containing 'save' & 'cancel' button as shown below. I
   don't want this to happen. Instead the screen should look like as
   shown in 2nd image.

[image]

Below is the XAML code i tried.

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Name="txtLimit" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Enter the value" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}"/> 
        <TextBox AcceptsReturn="True" InputScope="Number"  />
    </StackPanel>

    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Orientation="Horizontal" >
        <Button Content="save" Width="200" />
        <Button Content="cancel" Width="200"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 2):

For setting the focus for first time navigation you apparently have to set this in the `Loaded` event handler.

For back navigation (from when you application is switched away), the one in `OnNavigatedTo` will fire as you'd expect.

```
    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Loaded += (sender, args) => this.textBox.Focus();
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        this.textBox.Focus();
    }
```

However you will need to add your buttons to the `ApplicationBar` to show below the on-screen keyboard.

However the SDK doesn't allow use of rectangular buttons in the application bar, only icon buttons.

Comment: So this kind of behaviour is specific to OS and exposed to developers ? 

I doubt if we can customize appbar to even hide those 3 dots if i don't use menu items. Is there no other way to achieve this ? 

What about setting focus to textbox once the user is navigated to the page ?

Comment: Answer updated for the textbox focus. I'm not aware of any other way of doing what you want apart from writing your own on-screen keyboard which is no small undertaking.

Comment: this.textBox.Focus(); does not work in WP8. Did it in TextBox_Loaded event.  

(sender as TextBox).Focus();

Comment: The code above worked for me on a brand new WP8 project - but note the *two* places `Focus()` is called.

Answer (score 0):

In the OnNavigatedTo method, can you try to use the Dispatcher like this :

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(()=>{
    this.textBox.Focus();
  });
```

And, as pointed out, you can NOT have rectangular buttons in the appBar but you can use standard one (like the linked in button for example).

Comment: I tried this first in a very simple WP8 project while coming up with my answer above. It didn't work...